# Why should I import keras again even if after importing tensorflow2?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow version2, when I want to use tf.keras, all the example codes import keras again even if tensorflow has imported like below example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.kera...
```

Can't I just skip second line which is `from tensorflow import keras`?? Why should I import keras separately even if I use keras in forms of `tf.keras`??

Comment: If you are using `tf.keras..` you can skip importing keras separately. Some people import it so that they do not have to type out `tf` .

Comment: So in ```https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification?hl=en``` this document, is ```from tensorflow import keras``` in example code not necessary?

Comment: You can skip importing Keras, but you will have to write `tf.keras` every time you intend to call `Keras`